# Q: Two independent sequences of Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Two players conduct simultaneously and independently a sequence of Bernoulli trials. Both have a probability $p$ for success in each Bernoulli trial. 
What is the probability that the first player will have $i$ successes until (and including) the trial in which the second player will have the first success?

My try for a solution:

$X$ - Number of successes for the first player.

$Y$ - Number of the trial in which the second player had the first success.

$X\sim Bin(n,p)$

$Y\sim Geom(p)$

$P((X=i)\cap(Y=n))={n \choose i}p^{i+1}(1-p)^{2n-i-1}$

First of all, I'm not sure this is the correct solution.
Secondly, in case this is the correct solution, is there a way to further simplify ${n \choose i}p^{i+1}(1-p)^{2n-i-1}$?

Comment: Try to use the total probability formula
$
P(X=i) = \sum_{n\ge i}^{\infty} P(X=i|Y=n)P(Y=n).
$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{X_n\}$ and $\{Y_n\}$ be the iid $\operatorname{Ber}(p)$ sequences. Let
$$
S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k
$$
and
$$N=\inf\{N:Y_n=1\}. $$
Then we want to find the distribution of $S_N$. (This is a compound binomial-geometric distribution.) By independence, we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(S_N=0) &= \sum_{m=1}^\infty \mathbb P(S_N=0\mid N=m)\mathbb P(N=m)\\
&= \sum_{m=1}^\infty \mathbb P(S_m=0)\mathbb P(N=m)\\
&= \sum_{m=1}^\infty (1-p)^m p (1-p)^{m-1}\\
&= \frac{1-p}{2-p},
\end{align}
and for $n\geqslant 1$
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(S_N=n) &= \sum_m \mathbb P(S_N=n\mid N=m)\mathbb P(N=m)\\
&=\sum_{m=n}^\infty \mathbb P(S_m = n)\mathbb P(N=m)\\
&=\sum_{m=n}^\infty \binom mn p^n(1-p)^{m-n} p(1-p)^{m-1}\\
&=\left(\frac p{1-p}\right)^{n+1}\sum_{m=n}^\infty\binom mn (1-p)^{2m}\\
&= \frac{(1-p)^{n-1}}{(2-p)^{n+1}}.
\end{align}